# Unpacking argument in print statements

Tags: python, argument-unpacking

I would like to know if there is a way to unpack values in a print statement, the same way it is possible to unpack arguments in a function `f`

This works:

```
import numpy
er = numpy.array([0.36666667, 0.46666667, 0.43333333, numpy.nan])
l = 0.8
print('%0.3f | %0.3f | %0.3f | %0.3f | %0.1f' % (er[0], er[1], er[2], er[3], l))
# 0.367 | 0.467 | 0.433 | nan | 0.8
```

However, I would like to avoid multiple `er[x]` and instead use something like `*er` as in:

```
def f(a,b,c,d):
    return True
print(f(*er))
# True
```

I tried:

```
#print('%0.3f | %0.3f | %0.3f | %0.3f | %0.1f' % (*(er, numpy.array([l]))))
```

But this last line generates "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a closing `)`.

Comment: You can: `print('{} {}'.format(*[1, 2]))`

Comment: @timgeb Fix it, still got the same error

Comment: How about using list comprehension to create a list from the ers first, add the l and then print out the generated list?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Nice. I forget to precise that I really need the output format with '|' since I'm generating some markdown table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need the specific format you can do the following which allows both for the definition of separators (`' | '`) as well as formatting of the individual values (`{:.3f}`):

```
print(' | '.join(['{:.3f}'.format(x) for x in er]))
```

Adding values to that is trivial:

```
print(' | '.join(['{:.3f}'.format(x) for x in er]) + ' | {:.1f}'.format(l))
```

Note that the `str.join()` performs faster when provided with a `list` rather than a generator expression.

Comment: *note: list comprehension is used because it's faster than genexp with `str.join`.

Comment: The second line gives me this error - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: It should be changed to this - `print(' | '.join(['{:.3f}'.format(x) for x in er] + ['{:.1f}'.format(l)]))`

Comment: @SRC I mixed the parentheses, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
print('{:.3f} | {:.3f} | {:.3f} | {:.1f} | {:.3f}'.format(*(list(er) + [l])))
```

Make sure all your args are in one place before you unpack them.

Comment: Numpy arrays have a `copy` method on them. Also copying just for the print seems wasteful.

Comment: @timgeb I agree. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! (NB: `import copy` isn't necessary anymore with this version)

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do't want to unpack anything because you want a tuple after `%`.

```
print('%0.3f | %0.3f | %0.3f | %0.3f | %0.1f' % (tuple(er) + (1,)))
0.367 | 0.467 | 0.433 | nan | 1.0
```

But you'd better use `str.format`. Unpacking makes sense here because you want to pass every array item as an argument to the function.

```
print('{:0.3f} | {:0.3f} | {:0.3f} | {:0.3f} | {:0.1f}'.format(*er, 1))
0.367 | 0.467 | 0.433 | nan | 1.0
```

Comment: The as-a-tuple trick is what I was looking for. Thanks!